# 'apply' of undefined error when redirecting in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to redirect to a different page when i get a success response in my API call.

I get the following error when trying to do this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

I have created a redirect function in a js file called redirect.js and import it in my action to use it.

**redirect.js**

```
import {push} from 'react-router-redux';

export function redirect(route) {

    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(push(route))
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const middleware = routerMiddleware('');

const store = createStore(ReducerStore, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(middleware, thunk),
),)

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**Usage**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from './global/apiUrl.js';
import {redirect} from './global/redirect.js';

export function registerUser(data) {

    const regData = JSON.stringify(data);

    return dispatch => {

        axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/****/******?*****=${regData}`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then(res => {
                const { response } = res.data;
                if (response === 200) {
                    alert("Registration success");
                    dispatch(redirect('/account_created'))
                } else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            })

    }
}
```

NOTE: I have installed the redux dev tool extension as well.

Comment: Can you provide your `actions` and `reducers` defined for the routing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `index.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
const store = createStore(ReducerStore, compose(
    applyMiddleware(middleware, thunk)
))
```